# Passing multiple jQuery objects as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jquery-selectors

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this in jQuery:

```
$( [ $selector1, $selector2, document.getElemetByID( 'test' ) ] )
```

EDIT: I'm lazy. `$selector1` and `$selector2` are already jQuery objects. I am trying to avoid using `$.each`.

Here's a more in-depth example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var $lastLink = $( '.links' ).filter( ':last' );
var $nextThumbnail = $( '.thumbnail.current' ).next();
```

Let's say I want to add a class of `active` to those things and I would like to keep it as simple as possible - therefore I am looking for something with similar syntax to what I posted before.

```
$( [ $lastLink, $nextThumbnail ] ).addClass( 'active' );
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do with that?  What are you hoping for as the result?

Comment: `$("selector1", "selector2", document.getElementById("test"))` comma delimit for multiple selectors

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Maybe . .. or he could be looking for `$("selector1, selector2, #test"))`.  Hard to tell, based on how he's written it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher The first argument will be a  _selector_ and the second one the _context_.

Comment: The specifics of the selector don't really matter, but I saw it as multiple selectors. That's why I didn't post as answer lol

Comment: Ahh shoot @Vohuman you're right

Comment: I just edited my question folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Yes, but not exactly like that. If each of your $selector variables represents a collection of a *single* DOM element, you can rewrite your code like this:

`$([$selector1[0], $selector2[0], document.getElementByID('test')])`

And you will be able to add a class to all of those elements at once without .each()

Comment: Yeah, but I still need to use `$.each` - I wanted to specifically avoid this.

Comment: I guess you've got a little typo. The opening square bracket is missing after `$(`.  Great answer, though!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo Thanks for pointing that out, missed it in my haste to type

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it supports it within a single function call.

But, you could chain calls to [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$().add($selector1).add($selector2).add(document.getElementById('test'))
```

When given an `Array`, `jQuery()` generally expects the contents to [already be `Element`s](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray). Otherwise, it treats it as using the [`jQuery(object)` overload](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object), leaving the strings as is.

```
console.log( $(['#foo', '#bar']).get() ); // [ '#foo', '#bar' ]
```

Comment: While this is not really what I'm looking for, it's pretty close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is "no".
JQuery does not expect `array` as selector.

Its either a comma-separated string list, or a single DOM object or a jQuery object.

A second argument is treated as the "parent" container within which to conduct the search.

If you insist on collecting several objects into one, an option is to do this:

```
$($selector1).add( $selector2).add(document.getElemetByID( 'test' ))
```